# execute script to open terminal to run root commands

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I’m looking to run a shell script by double-clicking it from desktop gui for my ubuntu server (v20).

I would like the shell script to run these commands in a terminal window when I double click it:

- sudo -i
  (prompt for password)
  *then under root* =
- xhost +
- unset XAUTHORITY
- export DISPLAY=:0
- ssa -local

it must run in that order as I have to do this so I can run hp ssa under root

I’ve tried all sorts of ways to get it to run, but I cannot. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 server install, and not a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server install (the 20 is used to signify a *snap* only product, the 20.04 or *year.month* format is used for *deb* based products).

Comment: @guiverc, its just a normal 20.04 install

Comment: Well please say so (ie. edit your question & I can remove my comment(s)), as 20 and 20.04 are different products; Ubuntu uses the *year.month* format for *deb* based products, and *year* format only for specialist *snap* only products (20 has 10 year supported life; longer than 20.04 LTS which has 5 years of *standard* that can be extended an extra 5 years via ESM... the products differ...)

Answer (score 0):

For Gnome Terminal, which comes with a default Ubuntu install, that can be achieved with a custom profile. In the Preferences dialog, create a new profile, e.g. `rootshell`. On the "Command" tab of the new profile, specify your shell script as "Custom command". That can be exactly as you hinted to, however preferably include a shebang.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -i
xhost +
unset XAUTHORITY
export DISPLAY=:0
ssa -local
```

In your `.desktop` launcher, launch this custom terminal as:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=rootshell
```

Double-clicking the launcher will start Gnome Terminal with the custom profile. On startup, Gnome Terminal will run the script: your user password is asked to elevate priviledges to root. Subsequent commands are executed, and finally, you are dropped at a root prompt, with an environment customized through your script.

If you use a different terminal emulator, a similar approach will apply in most cases. However, details on how to configure will vary.